# How can I switch between all windows of my host and VirtualBox guest system using Alt+Tab?

Tags: unity, virtualbox, window

My host system is Ubuntu 16.04. I run Windows 7 in a VirtualBox machine.

I would like to use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> to switch between all windows of both my host and virtual guest system.

**The following video demonstrates the problem:** 
[Video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2YogA4Oyfg&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 1):

With VirtualBox’s Seamless Mode you can Combine Two Operating Systems Into One Desktop. This feature turns on with keys `ctrl+L`

Comment: I switched into seamless mode and pressed `Alt+Tab`. However, it still only switches either between the windows running in my host or my guest system but not both.